# Sync PDA time and date without starting Windows mobile device center

Tags: synchronization, windows-mobile, windows-ce, wmdc

I'm using a PDA (Motorola MC50) to scan bar codes and after that I plug it in and the data is uploaded into my application. What i'm trying to achieve is to sync the PDA time and date without having to open WMDC or at most to setup my device once and after that to be able to sync without having to start WMDC..  When I plug in my device i see 3 different processes related to it: wmdc.exe, WmdHost.exe and mobsync.exe. I tried to kill each one of them to see which one deals with the time and date update and it seems that wmdc.exe is doing this part.

Also I receive an error message saying that "There is no email program associated to perform the requested action" when I plug in  the PDA.

What I basically need to know is if it's possible to have the time and date updated on the PDA done in the background without starting WMDC and receiving that error message. Can I somehow use the module which updates the time and date separately, is there anything in the registry that can be changed?
I already asked the vendor of the PDA but they said that this is related to the OS
I hope my description is clear, if not ask me what you don't understand.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are already posts about syncing time with PC and activesync/wmdc: [Setting Windows Mobile device system time from computer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14805345/setting-windows-mobile-device-system-time-from-computer/14806749#14806749)

The other part of the question (no email setup) can be avoided by using the GuestOnly Registry key and not using a partnership setup: http://www.hjgode.de/wp/2010/02/26/disable-the-activesync-partnership-setup-dialog/

REGEDIT4
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows CE Services]
“GuestOnly”=dword:00000001

For wmdc automation see http://www.hjgode.de/wp/2010/02/26/pc-activesync-can-be-used-to-automate-tasks-on-device-connection/

You can not simply isolate the program part of WMDC that syncs the time.